# Як утворити по батькові для імені Олесь?

Tags: власні-назви, словотворення

Мого брата звати Олесь і в нашій сім`ї неодноразово піднімалась тема того, яке по батькові буде у його дітей у майбутньому.

Справа в тому, що знайомих з таким іменем, окрім нього, у мене немає, а інтернет у даному питанні не дуже допомагає.

[Тут](http://uk.rodovid.org/wk/%D0%A1%D1%96%D0%BC%60%D1%8F:183165) містяться відомості про Гончара Олеся (Олександра) Терентійовича та його дітей. Але, зважаючи на те, що народився він з іменем "Олександр", а "Олесь" додалось вже у шкільні часи, то діти "Олександровичі".

Інших відомих людей з іменем Олесь не спадає на думку, аби перевірити, як правильно утворити по батькові від такого імені. А форма "Олесьович" не зовсім не звучить, хоча, можливо це зумовлене тим, що просто незвично таку чути.

*То як правильно буде утворити по батькові від імені Олесь?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У [Словнику UA](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) знаходимо:

> Олесьович — чоловіче ім'я по батькові (від Олесь).
>
> Олесівна — жіноче ім'я по батькові (від Олесь).

Також у [Деклараціях](https://declarations.com.ua/declaration/nacp_33035e21-4dbd-4598-8855-ff86e0fd986a) зазначено:

> Тютюнник Олександр Олесьович
>
> Мазур Людмила Олесівна

Отже, за допомогою суфікса **-ович/-івна** (див. також [Творення і правопис імен по батькові](http://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_and_spelling/creation_surname.html)) твориться по-батькові від "**Олесь**".

П. С. Якщо у паспорті пише "Олесь", то Олесьович, якщо Олександр — Олександрович.

Comment: просто питання, - Чи можливий варіант із суфіксом -евич? Олесевич? Чи це русизм?

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо неможливо, диви сусіднього відпису.

Answer (score 6):

**Згідно з чинним правописом 2015**

[***ПРАВОПИС СУФІКСІВ***](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par22p10)
**§ 22.**

> **-ОВИЧ, -ІВН(А) [-ЇВН(А)]**
>
> 10. При творенні чоловічих імен по батькові вживається тільки суфікс **-ович**: Васильович, Дорошович, Ігорович, Микитович, Олексійович, Юрійович.
>
> При творенні жіночих імен по батькові вживається суфікс -івн(а), від
>   імен на **-й — -ївн(а)**: Борисівна, Василівна; Гордіївна, Сергіївна,
>   Юріївна. /31/
>
> Від таких імен, як Григорій, Ілля, Кузьма, Лука, Микола, Сава, Хома,
>   Яків, відповідні імена по батькові будуть: Григорович, Григорівна;
>   Ілліч, Іллівна; Кузьмич (і Кузьмович), Кузьмівна; Лукич, Луківна;
>   Миколайович (і Миколович), Миколаївна (і Миколівна); Савич (і
>   Савович), Савівна; Хомич (і Хомович), Хомівна; Якович, Яківна.
>
> Примітка. При творенні імен по батькові в основах імен відбувається
>   чергування **і** з **о**: Антін — Антонович, Антонівна; Федір — Федорович,
>   Федорівна.

***Отже, Олесьович та Олесівна***